# How do I run a salt state on a running docker container

Tags: docker, salt-stack, configuration-management

Is there any way to run a shell command as part of a Salt state inside of a running docker container? I find the whole [dockerng](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.dockerng.html) module in Salt very confusing, because it only lists ad hoc commands.

From what I can grasp from the docs it should work like this:

```
mystate:
    dockerng.run:
      - name: 12345
      - cmd: bash -l -c ifconfig
```

That doesn't seem to be the case.

The command on the master:

```
 sudo salt-ssh -i box_with_docker_containers state.apply
```

The error:

> State 'dockerng.run' was not found in SLS

Comment: Do you mean dockerng.running instead of dockerng.run ? https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.dockerng.html#salt.states.dockerng.running

Comment: No, the container is started and up. I can attach to it, and run a bash command. That's what I want Salt to do.

Comment: `dockerng` has no `run` function, you can use `dockerio.run` to run a command inside a container https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.dockerio.html#salt.states.dockerio.run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The dockerng.run module:

The `dockerng` modules includes a `run` function:

```
mystate:
  module.run:
    - name: dockerng.run
    - m_name: 12345
    - cmd: bash -l -c ifconfig
```

The **name** is the name of the module, **m_name** the container name or ID in which to run the command and **cmd** is the command.

See the [salt.modules.dockerng](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.dockerng.html#salt.modules.dockerng.run) documentation for more information about the `dockerng` module.

See [salt.states.module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.module.html) for more information about running modules from within a state.

## The deprecated dockerio.run state:

Using the [dockerio.run](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.dockerio.html#salt.states.dockerio.run) you can run a command in a specific container:

```
mystate:
  dockerio.run:
    - name: bash -l -c ifconfig
    - cid: 12345
```

The **name** is the command to run in the container and the **cid** the Container id or name.

Note that the `dockerio` is deprecated since version 2015.8.0, future feature development will be done only in `dockerng`.